# In a Time Series Problem, is it possible to forecast quantities by learning the patterns of other items? What are my options?

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, r, time-series

Suppose I own a store that sells a variety of apples and I have the following stats each month.

- Report Date
- Type of Apple (TA)
- Quantity Available(QA)
- Quantity Sold in the Past 30 days(QS30)
- Quantity Shipping In (QSI)
- Quantity Needed to Order(QN)

Lets make the following assumptions/givens:

- There are three types of apples: red apples, green apples and yellow apples.
- T(1) denotes the first month and T(60) denotes the 60th month.
- QA @ T(i + 1) = QA@T(i) + QSI@T(i) - QS30@T(i+1)

---

I can provide all the data from T1-60 for each apple.

I can also provide all the data for T61 besides QN for each apple.

My goal is predict QN at T61, or the 61st month for each apple.

---

If I am only concerned about Red Apples, I can just use ARIMAX with data pertaining to only red apples or VAR right?

But what if I suddenly introduce a new apple type such as orange apples and only have a history from T1-4?

Given I need to use T1-4 for the orange apples...
Is it possible to use other data from the red, green and yellow to aid in properly calculating a QN value for orange apples at T5?

Answer (score 0):

*If I am only concerned about Red Apples, I can just use ARIMAX with data pertaining to only red apples or VAR right?*

Yes, is possible, you will lose information (perhaps valuable) but you can work with it.

*But what if I suddenly introduce a new apple type such as orange apples and only have a history from T1-4?*

*Given I need to use T1-4 for the orange apples... Is it possible to use other data from the red, green and yellow to aid in properly calculating a QN value for orange apples at T5?*

You will be limited to the knowledge of the orange apples but the other variables might help you obtain enough information until you could have a more robust model, 4 entries might not be enough, but the model might help you obtain an estimation